# How do I add an Arabic abstract before the English abstract?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, arabic, abstract

I want to add an Arabic abstract before the English abstract, at the beginning of an English document.

I also want the title of the abstract to appear in Arabic (ملخص) in the Table of Contents. here you are an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}  % ociamthesis
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\clearpage \pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\chapter*{ملخص}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\arabicabstractname}}

اء المعلومات هي تقنية متقدمة لإخفاء الييااات حيث تم اليحث فيها على اطاق واسع في السنوات الأخيرة اظر

\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

Data masking is an advanced data hiding technique where it has been extensively researched in recent years

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}


\end{document}
```

PS: i want that the code will not change my original font which is  Charter BT. Also, if it is possible, i want to build the file using pdftex, not xetec

Comment: Can you please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing your language set up. e.g., do you use `polyglossia` or `babel` or `arabtex` or … and which engine: `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 4):

I would have a better idea what you’re looking for if you’d provided a Minimal Working Example, but you might try tweaking this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Solely to make the output narrow enough for TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}
\babelprovide[main, import=en, language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Numbers=OldStyle]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase]{Amiri}
% You might also want to define \babelfont{sf} and \babelfont{tt}.

\renewcommand{\arabicabstractname}{ملخص}

\begin{document}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\arabicabstractname}}
  \selectlanguage{arabic}
  \begin{abstract}
    الخط الأميري خط نسخي موجه لطباعة الكتب و النصوص الطويلة.

    \selectlanguage{english}
    Amiri is a classical Arabic typeface in Naskh style for typesetting
    books and other running text.
  \end{abstract}

  \selectlanguage{english}
% From here on out, use \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic} for paragraphs, or
% \foreignlanguage{arabic} for short phrases.

  \tableofcontents

  \section{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image: Amiri/Libertinus sample]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works

Comment: however, the original font of the document changed, what can i do to preserve it ?

Comment: Also, make sure you have version 3.27 or higher of the `babel` package. That’s what I tested with.

Comment: The font is determined by the `\babelfont` commands. Since you did’t specify them or give an example, I picked Khaled Hosny’s Libertinus and Amiri. Choose any other TrueType or OpenType fonts you want instead.

Comment: I want to preserve the font of the template, how can know the type used by template? and use it with babel?

Comment: I can’t tell you what your template does, because you haven’t posted it. However, your PDF viewer should show you which fonts a document generated with the template uses.

Comment: i found this in pdf viewer : CharterBT-roman, how can i use it in  your exapmle ? thanks in advance

Comment: That would be Bitstream Charter. [There’s a version here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Charter), or you might find Georgia a decent substitute. The original document must use a different Arabic font, or you can use one of your choice.

Comment: i have just add MWE , please help, @ Davislor

Comment: @HamzaKHEDDAR The code in the edited question does not compile, so it’s not a minimal working example. If what you want is to change the font to a different OpenType or TrueType font, such as Bitstream Charter,, then you’d edit the `\babelfont` commands in the preamble to change the font name. If you actually need to use an 8-bit Type 1 font in 2019 together with Unicode, that’d be a lot more work, but you could do it with `luainputenc`.

Comment: A bit belated, but: if you want Bitstream Charter as the English font, you can change the first `\babelfont` to select `XCharter` instead of Libertinus Serif. XCharter is a conversion of Bitstream Charter. You can also choose a different Arabic font instead of Amiri.