# How to write in latex in multiple languages in the same document

Tags: babel, languages, overleaf

I have a document where I need to write in both english and arabic, in the preamble I added:

```
 \usepackage{arabtex}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
```

I am using the [Latex arabic example in overleaf](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/new/template?zipUrl=/project/5304cefb6a6237452e006b5e/download/zip&templateName=ArabicExample&compiler=pdflatex). Just added `english`.

The full corresponding source code is bellow:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\title{
\Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}

    ...يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين                                                   


\section{English section}
Trying to type in English but it doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

I couldn't compile the document and got this error:

> LaTeX Error: Command \ayn unavailable in encoding OT1.

Comment: Are you able to use LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX, or is a publisher forcing you to use PDFLaTeX?

Comment: If so, you might use [a template like this one.](https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-arabic.tex) It lets you use any Arabic font on your system and cuts the Gordian knot of how to juggle obsolete 8-bit fonts.

Comment: [I’ve given some templates of my own here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483950/how-do-i-add-an-arabic-abstract-before-the-english-abstract/483982#483982)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Disclaimer/Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]*

If you need to compile your project using pdflatex (perhaps due to a journal publisher requirement), then your code just needs a few more changes:

Assuming that you want to typeset your document in mainly Arabic with some English sections, you should load `arabic` as the last option for `babel`, or mark it explicitly as `main`:

```
\usepackage[main=arabic,english]{babel}
```

Then mark the English text as "otherlanguage":

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\section{English section}
Trying to type in English, it works now.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

---

If you need to keep the main language as English: then it's the Arabic text portions that need to be wrapped in `\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}...\end{otherlanguage}`. `fontenc` also needs an extra `T1` option explicitly. Complete reworked example of your code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}

\title{
\Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\maketitle
\end{otherlanguage}

\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}

    ...يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين                                                 
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{English section}
Trying to type in English; it works now.

\end{document}
```

---

If you *are* allowed to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then see these help pages on Overleaf on using `fontspec` to choose fonts. XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX are more robust at handling unicode input. You can use [`polyglossia`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_polyglossia_and_fontspec) or [`babel`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_babel_and_fontspec).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works when Arabic is the main language, however, I am trying to do the opposite (I put english as main and arabic as other language), the arabic display is correct in this case , but it doesnt work for the english part which is displayed in arabic characters. I am using pdflatex

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example for when English is the babel main language.