# Roman page numbering is not working when the document is written in Arabic

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, arabic

I wrote a document in both English and Arabic. When I try to run the command `\pagenumbering{roman}` and the document is written only in English, it works. However, after adding the Arabic language with its necessary packages, all the page numbers are displayed in Arabic. Here is the code based on [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550639/how-to-write-in-latex-in-multiple-languages-in-the-same-document/550663?noredirect=1#comment1393598_550663):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}

\title{
\Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\maketitle
\end{otherlanguage}

\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}

    ...يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين                                                 
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{English section}
Trying to type in English; it works now.

\end{document}
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the TeX engine to luatex or xetex?

Comment: You could try using `\let\normalpage=\thepage` outside the environment and `\let\thepage=\normalpage` inside.  If that doesn't work, try \roman instead of \thepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can compile with LuaLaTeX instead, the following works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import,onchars=ids fonts]{arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Renderer=HarfBuzz, Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common,Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}

\title{
\Huge{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\maketitle
\end{otherlanguage}

\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}

    ...يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين                                                 
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{English section}
Trying to type in English; it works now.

\end{document}
```

In PDFLaTeX, I didn’t get `\pagenumbering{roman}` to work properly, but by giving `babel` the `bidi` and `layout` options, you can at least have section formats and numbers appear consistently:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bidi=default,layout=counters.sectioning,arabic,main=english]{babel}

\title{
\Huge{اللغة العربية}
}
\author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\maketitle
\end{otherlanguage}

\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}

    ...يعود تاريخ علوم الحاسوب إلى اختراع أول حاسوب رقمي حديث. فقبل العشرينات من القرن العشرين                                                 
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{English section}
Trying to type in English; it works now.

\end{document}
```