# Babel & Bilingual fonts

Tags: fonts, babel, arabic

I am using Babel package to support Arabic and English in one document. But I am not able to identify a multilingual font that supports Bold typeface. The code below works fine, but lacks the bold typeface.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[english, arabic, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{times}
\newtheorem{theorem}{نظرية}[section]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{مقدمة Introduction}
    test1
    \textbf{hi}
    \begin{theorem}
    \end{theorem}
    \newpage
    test2 تجربة
\end{document}
```

If I change the font to Arial, the bold works but somehow the Arabic word in the footnote gets scrambled. Only in the footnote, all other places are fine! see below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any font on your system or in your TeX directory, for example, Khaled Hosny’s [Amiri](https://www.amirifont.org/).

You could also specify a different Arabic font, for example, `\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Naskh Arabic}`.

Here is [one of many templates you might start from](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483950/how-do-i-add-an-arabic-abstract-before-the-english-abstract/483982#483982).

However, most fonts should be available in bold.  If you have a bold version of the font installed, but it is not displaying properly, you might try loading all of its faces by filename, such as, for example:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Amiri]{
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  SlantedFont = *-Slanted ,
  BoldSlantedFont = *-BoldSlanted ,
  Extension = .otf}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
```

Comment: After some tweaking I found Amiri to work, although I would still prefer some other Arabic fonts, e.g. Times. Why don't all Arabic fonts support regular & bold typefaces simultaneously?

Comment: @student1 Most do that I’m aware of. There are many versions of Times out there, and I do not know which one you have.